# How do I edit and save a large bitmap in Android? Currently writing it out as tiles but it is slow to join them back together

Tags: android, bitmap, renderscript

I'm using renderscript on Android to edit photos, currently due to the texture size limit and memory limits on Android the app will crash if I try anything too large eg photos taken with the devices camera.

My first thought to get around this was to use BitmapRegionDecoder and tile the large photo into manageable pieces, edit them through renderscript and save them one at a time, then stitch it all together using PNGJ - a PNG decoding and encoding library that allows writing PNG images to disk in parts so I don't have the full image in memory.

This works fine but stitching it together takes a rather long time - around 1 minute at a guess.

Are there any other solutions I should consider? I can change to JPEG if there is a solution there, but I haven't found it yet. Basically I'm looking for the other side of a BitmapRegionDecoder, a BitmapRegionEncoder.

Just to be clear, I do not want to resize the image.

Comment: @Ata Please read the question as none of the libraries you have mentioned help me.

Comment: What I understand is you need some kindof transformer and leave the loading/saving to the library. The transformer lets you change the image like you want to. Try this https://code.facebook.com/projects/465232426958622/fresco/

Comment: Have you looked at the AOSP Gallery2 app? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/android-5.1.1_r13

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks, will check it out. I'm currently looking into using JNI.

Comment: If you are first saving and then stitching you are doing compression and decompression twice, plus unnecessary disk access. Can't you just process/save several rows at a time?

Comment: @MiloslawSmyk Good point, I hadn't though about using PNGJ just to write them to the final file as they are edited, I will see if that cuts down the time at all.

Comment: @MiloslawSmyk After a brief look this doesn't seem to be possible with PNGJ at least as it requires writing 1 complete row of pixels at a time.

Comment: @Aardvark545 So how many rows at a time does your Renderscript code need? 64 rows (which is sufficient for most shaders) and 20Mpx image requires just about 64 x 5000 x 4 x 2 = ~2.4MB, which you should be able to fit in memory easily.

Comment: @MiloslawSmyk 5000x64 would not fit within the texture size limit though - width seems to be 2048 on my Galaxy S4. Not sure how many renderscript requires as a minimum but none of my transforms to the pixels rely on other pixels so my minimum is any.

Comment: @Aardvark545 Why are you relying on textures? Can't you use Allocations?

Comment: @MiloslawSmyk I am using allocations but if I try to use renderscript with an image larger than the maximum texture size then it won't work.

Comment: @Aardvark545 Interesting. I have just clocked 4850x3635 image at 7 seconds doing loading, simple rs and saving to PNG (64 full-width rows at a time), then at nearly 3 minutes doing exactly the same but with alpha channel. This on OnePlus One. Nexus 5 was some 20% slower. Will dig more.

Comment: @Aardvark545 It works on HTC One M7 and GNex, too. Can you post your code creating the Allocations?

Comment: @MiloslawSmyk Hmm, this seems to work for me also - well actually I managed to edit a full 4128x2322 image and save without writing it line by line and I received no out of memory crashes. I'm not sure where the issues with the texture limit came from originally but I'm no longer having them. Interesting that the alpha channel added that much time, I suppose it makes sense though. Maybe I attempted to optimise a bit prematurely. I may have to come back to this at some point though.

Comment: Just for the record, I think it was not the alpha channel by itself, but rather the different data layout that made the deflate compressor's job more difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Load the image in horizontal stripes using `BitmapRegionDecoder`. The code below assumes that it is PNG and uses PNGJ to copy the metadata to new image, but adding support for JPEG should not be too difficult.
2. Process each stripe with Renderscript.
3. Save it using PNGJ. Do not use high compression or it will slow down to a crawl.

PNG version of [this image](http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/52bc7f8decad04b6116949eb/bill-gates-2013-was-a-huge-year-for-the-things-that-really-matter.jpg) (4850x3635px) takes 12 seconds on Nexus 5 with a trivial RS filter (desaturation).

```
void processPng(String forig,String fdest) {
    try {
        Allocation inAllocation = null;
        Allocation outAllocation = null;
        final int block_height = 64;

        FileInputStream orig = new FileInputStream(forig);
        FileInputStream orig2 = new FileInputStream(forig);
        FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(fdest);

        BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(orig, false);
        Rect blockRect = new Rect();

        PngReader pngr = new PngReader(orig2);
        PngWriter pngw = new PngWriter(dest, pngr.imgInfo);
        pngw.copyChunksFrom(pngr.getChunksList());

        // keep compression quick
        pngw.getPixelsWriter().setDeflaterCompLevel(1);

        int channels = 3; // needles to say, this should not be hardcoded
        int width = pngr.imgInfo.samplesPerRow / channels;
        int height = pngr.imgInfo.rows;

        pngr.close(); // don't need it anymore

        blockRect.left = 0;
        blockRect.right = width;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap blockBitmap;
        byte []bytes = new byte[width * block_height * 4];
        byte []byteline = new byte[width * channels];

        for (int row = 0; row <= height / block_height; row++) {
            int h;

            // are we nearing the end?
            if((row + 1) *  block_height <= height)
                h = block_height;
            else {
                h = height - row * block_height;

                // so that new, smaller Allocations are created
                inAllocation = outAllocation = null;
            }

            blockRect.top = row * block_height;
            blockRect.bottom = row * block_height + h;

            blockBitmap = decoder.decodeRegion(blockRect, options);

            if(inAllocation == null)
                inAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, blockBitmap);

            if(outAllocation == null)
            {
                Type.Builder TypeDir = new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.U8_4(mRS));
                TypeDir.setX(width).setY(h);

                outAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, TypeDir.create());
            }

            inAllocation.copyFrom(blockBitmap);
            mScript.forEach_saturation(inAllocation, outAllocation);
            outAllocation.copyTo(bytes);

            int idx = 0;

            for(int raster = 0; raster < h; raster++) {
                for(int m = 0; m < width; m++)
                {
                    byteline[m * channels] = bytes[idx++];
                    byteline[m * channels + 1] = bytes[idx++];
                    byteline[m * channels + 2] = bytes[idx++];
                    idx++;
                }

                ImageLineByte line = new ImageLineByte(pngr.imgInfo, byteline);
                pngw.writeRow(line);
            }
        }
        pngw.end();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.d("BIG", "File io problem");
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the compression level and removing alpha in PNGJ made a big difference to the write time in my current code and the resulting file isn't too much bigger. I will optimise it further with your method of doing it 64 lines at a time and writing each to the PNG as they are done to prevent unnecessary disk access and encoding. Thanks

Comment: any solution for saving the image in JPEG in regions/lines?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @MiloslawSmyk answer, this is the version to load a large JPEG and save it with PNGJ:

```
fun processPng(forig: String, fdest: String) {
    try {
        val blockHeight = 64

        val orig = FileInputStream(forig)
        val dest = FileOutputStream(fdest)

        val decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(orig, false)
        val blockRect = Rect()

        val channels = 3 // needles to say, this should not be hardcoded
        val sizeOptions = BitmapFactory.Options().apply {
            inJustDecodeBounds = true
        }
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(forig, sizeOptions)
        val height: Int = sizeOptions.outHeight
        val width: Int = sizeOptions.outWidth

        val pngw = PngWriter(dest, ImageInfo(width, height, 8, false))

        // keep compression quick
        pngw.pixelsWriter.deflaterCompLevel = 1

        blockRect.left = 0
        blockRect.right = width

        val options = BitmapFactory.Options().apply {
            inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        }
        var blockBitmap: Bitmap
        val byteLine = ByteArray(width * channels)

        for (row in 0..height / blockHeight) {
            // are we nearing the end?
            val h: Int = if ((row + 1) * blockHeight <= height)
                            blockHeight
                        else {
                            height - row * blockHeight
                        }

            blockRect.top = row * blockHeight
            blockRect.bottom = row * blockHeight + h

            blockBitmap = decoder.decodeRegion(blockRect, options)

            // convert bitmap into byte array
            val size = blockBitmap.rowBytes * blockBitmap.height
            val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size)
            blockBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer)
            val bytes = byteBuffer.array()

            var idx = 0

            for (raster in 0 until h) {
                for (m in 0 until width) {
                    byteLine[m * channels] = bytes[idx++]
                    byteLine[m * channels + 1] = bytes[idx++]
                    byteLine[m * channels + 2] = bytes[idx++]
                    idx++
                }

                val line = ImageLineByte(pngw.imgInfo, byteLine)
                pngw.writeRow(line)
            }
        }
        pngw.end()

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.d("BIG", "File io problem")
    }

}
```